# Web API equivalent to Web Service [.asmx]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to Web API.  I have implemented some Web service methods [.asmx] using deprecated WebServices - with Attributes [WebMethod] and was able to place all my different methods in the .asmx file and was able to call them by the webmethod name in my ajax calls.

I am trying to move this to WebAPI, and i dont see that i could use different methods here in the WebAPI.

for ex., in my WebService.asmx file, i could declare :

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void LoadReport()
    {
        ...
    }


 [WebMethod]
    public void LoadReport2()
    {
      ...
    }
```

But in WebAPI, all i could utilize is the Get(), Put(), Post() and Delete().

How do i declare these 2 different methods in Web API ?

Comment: Consider reading documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attribute routing in web api.

for example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Data")]
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
      [Route("LoadReport")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage LoadReport()
            {
                ...
            }

        [Route("LoadReport2")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage LoadReport2()
            {
                ...
            }
```

you can access these methods by calling

```
http://localhost:<port>/api/sample/LoadReport
http://localhost:<port>/api/sample/LoadReport2
```

if you use .Net 4.5.2, ensure that the Attribute Routing is enabled.
Add the below line under `Register` method of App_Start\WebAPiConfig.cs file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{    
         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //enable Attribute routing
```

Comment: I followed your example and I am getting error message - {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:5172/api/Data/LoadReport'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Data' that matches the request."}

Comment: Hope you are using .Net 4.5.2. If yes then you need to enable the attribute routing. Please check my updated answer

Comment: @Kalyan you are mixing asp.net core and web API 2 code. I dont believe `[controlller]` place holder works in web api 2 and you also need to use `RoutePrefix` instead of `Route` on the controller. The actions are fine.

Comment: I am able to get the results, by adding action in the config.Route -   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",  and in my Controller , instead of [Route("LoadReport")], i changed to ActionName("LoadReport") along with [HttpGet] attribute.

Comment: Yes @Ron that will also work. that is using convention-based routing.

Comment: @Kalyan, yes , i have enabled the Attribute routing and it doesnt work.

Comment: Since you are using .Net 4.5.2 change the controller level attribute as [RoutePrefix("api/Data")]. Please check my updated answer

Comment: @Nkoshi: you are right. I was not sure which version of .Net framework he is using.

Answer (score 1):

In WebApiConfig.cs :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and in my Controller :

```
namespace WebAPIa.Controllers
{
   // [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
        [ActionName("LoadReport")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage LoadReport()
        {

           return Request.CreateResponse("Testing LoadReport");
        }

        [ActionName("LoadReport2")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage LoadReport2()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse("Testing LoadReport2");
        }
    }
}
```